# Counting datetime by comparing to date with SUMPRODUCT or COUNTIF based on criteria

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I'm trying to count the total applicants day by day. The conflict here is that the application date is on datetime, and the date on another sheet is date format.

Here's what I want to produce:

```
Sheet 1

**A**                 **B**
Applicant No.     Date Applied
Applicant1        2/25/2019 8:59:00
Applicant2        2/25/2019 8:12:45

Sheet 2

**A**                **B**
Date              Total Applicants
2/25/2019         2
```

I have tried this sumproduct:

```
=SUM((DATE(YEAR('sheet1'!B2:B13),MONTH('sheet1'!B2:B13),DAY('sheet1'!B2:B13))=DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2),DAY(A2))))
```

but the output is 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this into Sheet2!B2

```
=countifs(sheet1!B:B, ">="&A2, sheet1!B:B, "<"&A2+1)
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the fast response and effective answer :)